How to use bpmn-io/form-js in vue
I've been trying to use the form schema generated from Camunda to create a form on my front-end. According to their own docs they use @bpmn-io/form-js to load the forms which is an open source project. However, when I try to use it to load the form it is unable to find the form container at any point, does anyone happen to know why this might be?
The code:
<script lang="ts" setup>
import { onMounted } from "vue";
import { Form } from "@bpmn-io/form-js";

const formSchemaString = '{\n  "components": [\n    {\n      "text": "# Whats for Dinner?",\n      "label": "Text view",\n      "type": "text",\n      "layout": {\n        "row": "Row_0qhrhgs",\n        "columns": null\n      },\n      "id": "Field_1gcawnh"\n    },\n    {\n      "values": [\n        {\n          "label": "Chicken",\n          "value": "Chicken"\n        },\n        {\n          "label": "Salad",\n          "value": "Salad"\n        }\n      ],\n      "label": "Food",\n      "type": "radio",\n      "layout": {\n        "row": "Row_1w5annl",\n        "columns": null\n      },\n      "id": "Field_04ss86e",\n      "key": "meal"\n    }\n  ],\n  "type": "default",\n  "id": "dinner_form",\n  "executionPlatform": "Camunda Cloud",\n  "executionPlatformVersion": "8.6.0",\n  "exporter": {\n    "name": "Camunda Modeler",\n    "version": "5.28.0"\n  },\n  "schemaVersion": 16\n}';

onMounted(() => {
  const formContainer = document.querySelector("#form");
  const form = new Form({
    container: formContainer
  });

  const formSchema = JSON.parse(formSchemaString);

  form.importSchema(formSchema);
});
</script>

<template>
  <div class="form"></div>
</template>


The query selector #form queries by id, but in your template, you use class. Either set id="form" on the element or use the selector .form. Consider using template refs instead of query.
